# Counting number of balanced two-way partition of the set

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, set-partition

Given a set with $2n$ elements, show that the number of balanced two-way partition of the set $$P(2n)=\frac{2n!}{2\times n!\times n!}$$

I'm getting is as P(2n)=${2n}\choose{n}$. But I'm getting different ans, Am I assuming something wrong.

Comment: If you define the term "balanced" in the question, you might notice one of the two things that are wrong with your answer.

Comment: You might also notice the error in your statement of the problem.

Comment: Note that you can edit comments for five minutes; the edit link is at the end of the comment. (And if you notice an error as above after the five minutes have passed, you can still delete the comment and resubmit it with corrected formatting.)

Comment: @joriki I'm getting `2nCn=2n!/(n!*n!)` which still doesn't meets the ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, one of the mistakes in your answer is that you considered all partitions into two subsets, not just balanced partitions, i.e. partitions into subsets of equal size, and taking this into account improves your answer from $2^{2n}$ to $\binom{2n}n$. The missing factor of $2$ arises because conventionally, in partitioning sets into subsets, while one treats the elements of the set as distinguishable (in contrast to partitioning numbers, where only the size of the parts matters), one treats the subsets as indistinguishable, e.g. the partitions of $[1,2n]$ into $[1,n]$ and $[n+1,2n]$ and into $[n+1,2n]$ and $[1,n]$ are the same partition.

Comment: You are trying to say it should be `(2nCn) /2`

Comment: @Atinesh: I don't understand your comment. You yourself posted the question, in which $\binom{2n}n/2$ is given as the answer. I thought the question was how to arrive at that answer